# how to make a LAN between ubuntu in vmware and my host which it is win7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, vmware

I have vmware and I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on that I want to make LAN that with my host which is windows 7. I change my Windows Ethernet card to 192.168.1.1 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0,Also in ubuntu I set my etho to 192.168.1.3 . But when I ping 192.168.1.3 in windows 7 I just see destination unreachable and Vice Versa  I mean when I ping 192.168.1.2 in Ubuntu I see that ICMP message again I know there is something in Vmware Network interface configuration  between "Bridge" and "NAT" and "HostOnly" but I do not know HOW can fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using VMware Workstation.

It is not necessary to use the bridge mode which directly connects the virtual machine (guest) to the physical network the host machine (host = the physical machine) is connected to.

The other two basic options work too:

- **Host-only** - The guest is networked only with the host. For this to work you have to configure the interface on the guest and the interface `vmnet1` on the host to be in the same sub-net.
- **NAT** - The guest and the host are in the same network as in Host-only but in addition the host performs network address translation for guests so that they can communicate with other networks of the host through the NAT. Similarly to Host-only there is another interface - `vmnet2` on the host which can be used to guest <-> host communication.

VMware Workstation also contains a DHCP server. You can check the settings and change/create additional `vmnet` interfaces in Edit > Virtual Network Editor.

Do not forget to check the firewall settings both on host and guest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the virtual ethernet interface assigned to the Ubuntu guest in bridge mode. This way, the virtual machine is placed in the same subnet as the physical host and can have an IP in the same broadcast domain, allowing bidirectional communication over TCP/IP.